# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 -- flutter -- firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have recreated this error on a more general basis.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}
class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  List<int> intlist = [];
  List<String> stringList = [];

  Future getIDlist() async {
    List<int> list1 = [];
    List<int> list2 = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
      var firebaseShop = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Collection')
          .doc('Data')
          .get();
      var dataShop = firebaseShop.data();
      if (dataShop?['x']) { //Data is a boolean
        list1.add(i);
      } else {
        list2.add(i);
      }
    }
    intlist.addAll(list1);
    intlist.addAll(list2);
    stringList = intlist.map((int value) => value.toString()).toList();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(
        stringList[0],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Exception caught by widgets library:


The following RangeError was thrown building Test(dirty, state: _TestState#debf0):

**RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**
```

Just couldnt find an answer, hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You never called the `getIDlist()`, It will take some time to fetch data. It will be better to use `FutureBuilder` for future method.

So the `stringList` remain empty list and the error occurs.

For current shorcutway you can do

```dart
Future getIDlist() async {
 .....other code
  stringList = intlist.map((int value) => value.toString()).toList();
  setState((){});// to update ui after data fetch complete
}
```

And while rendering Text, do data check.

```dart
stringList.isNotEmpty? Text(stringList[0]) : null,
```

But for better practice, check [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and [firestore/query-data/get-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)